# How do mocking frameworks (in .Net) create mock objects?

Tags: .net, mocking, types

In the context of the Microsoft .Net Framework, I'm really curious about how mocking frameworks (Rhino Mocks, Moq, NMock, *etc.*) actually *create* the mock objects from a given type.

I'm interested in either the specific mechanics of one method or, if they use different methods perhaps some overview of the different ways.  Alternatively, if anyone could point me at some articles, that'd be great too.

Comment: This is a good question. You could drop the assembly into Reflector and take a look at the code to get started.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Castle DynamicProxy - http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html. A lot of the .NET mocking frameworks use this under the hood.

Comment: As flecther mentioned, [redgate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is a great program for figuring out what's going on inside a compiled assembly. It really is as easy as dragging and dropping the DLL into Reflector and inspecting the code.

Comment: I noticed that, when it comes to using it, DynamicProxy is very short on documentation.  I found an excellent tutorial series here:
http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/04/27/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There are different techniques out there for mocking.**

Some mocking libaries like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) and [RhinoMocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) use [Castle Dynamic proxies](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html). Essentially, they use reflection and runtime code generation (CodeDom) to dynamically generate classes that either implement an interface being mocked, or derive from a non-sealed class that's being mocked.

[TypeMock](http://site.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=search-brand&mdm=cpc&utm_content=1) is a bit different - it uses the Profiler APIs to intercept and redirect calls to any method on any type. This makes it capable of mocking sealed types, system classes, and even intercept and divert calls to non-virtual methods of concrete types.

UPDATE: From the [TypeMock website](http://www.typemock.com/Docs/writing_unit_tests_with_isolator.php):

> Typemock Isolator uses an Aspect-
>   Oriented programming design that
>   creates a mock aspect. Internally, it
>   uses the .NET framework profiler API
>   to monitor an application's execution.
>   When a method is called, the CLR
>   notifies Typemock Isolator. The
>   framework can then return mocked
>   values and override the original code
>   completely.

Comment: Does JustMock also use Debugger API? (BTW, I thought it was the Profiler API?)

Comment: @Russ Cam: I read up on it at one point, and I seem to recall it used the debugging APIs to intercept object creation and finalization. It may use the profiler APIs as well, since they are well suited to the kind of things it does. I'm not 100% certain, however, and I can't find the related doc at the moment.

Comment: @Russ Cam: I found the relevent info on the TypeMock website, it does look like it uses the profile API - and there's no mention of the debugger APIs, so I can't confirm if it uses that as well.